# Difference between zsh-history-substring-search and up-line-or-beginning-search

Tags: zsh, command-history

Is there a practical difference between [history-substring-search-up](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-history-substring-search) and [up-line-or-beginning-search](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/master/Functions/Zle/up-line-or-beginning-search)? I've tried both out and they effectively seem to do the same thing (besides some highlighting that history-substring-search does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`history-substring-search` takes the **whole** editing buffer and returns any history lines that contain it *anywhere* as a **substring**.

`up-line-or-beginning-search` takes only the part of the editing buffer that's **to the left** of the cursor and returns any history lines that **begin** with it.

---

PS: For more advanced/interactive versions of these features, check out the [`zsh-autocomplete` plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete).

[image: history search]